# Pass Core Data results to UILabel

Tags: iphone, uitableview, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext, nsfetchrequest

I'm selecting a row from a table. I want to pass the results of that selection to a UILabel on a new View. Do I need an NSFetchRequestController subroutine for the below? I wanted a simpler way to pass the event core data selection to a non-UITableView Controller (just a regular UIViewController).

The 'request' at objectIndexPath below is causing the error.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ReviewController *reviewViewController = [[ReviewController alloc] init];
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Event" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [request setEntity:entity];

    Event *selectedEvent = (Event *)[request objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    reviewViewController.event = selectedEvent; 
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:reviewViewController animated:YES];
    [reviewViewController release];
}
```

Comment: Vladimir, thanks, I was trying to fix the {} as you fixed it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a new fetched results controller. You just pass the managed object associated with the selected tableview row to the next controller. You are getting the error because you haven't performed a fetch and in any case a fetch request does not have a `objectAtIndexPath` method.

If you have a fetched results controller for the tableview, you find the selected object with:

```
reviewViewController.event =[[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] objectAtIndex:index.row];
```

Comment: I added a sort descriptor, and I think I'm getting close, I may come back with another question, but this is great.

Comment: I'm getting a comment that I need a sort descriptor. Why is that? I want to pull all the managed object content for the object selected from the table view? in addition, what would be your fetched objects above? The pointer from the fetchedresultscontroller?

Comment: TechZen, I reposed the new code here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5759742/passing-managed-object-context-to-a-new-view-controller-from-a-uitableview